# Expected Signature Algorithm does not match

Tags: single-sign-on, opensaml

I am trying to implement SSO. In my SP's metadata i have set signing and encryption algorithm to sha256

```
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="" />
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <ds:Reference URI="">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <ds:DigestValue />
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue />
    </ds:Signature>
```

and in my authentication request also I send request as:

```
 Signature signature = (Signature) Configuration.getBuilderFactory()
        .getBuilder(Signature.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME)
        .buildObject(Signature.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
    signature.setSignatureAlgorithm(SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA256);
    authnRequest.setSignature(signature);
    ((SAMLObjectContentReference)signature.getContentReferences().get(0)).setDigestAlgorithm(EncryptionConstants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA256);
```

And on my IDP side under Advanced tab of relying party, i cross check SHA-256 is set as hashing algorithm but now when i send authentication request i get error as:

```
  `SAML request is not signed with expected signature algorithm. SAML request is signed with signature algorithm` http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256 . Expected signature algorithm is http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
```

Please help me to resolve this issue, if I am missing out something somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me!

While sending authentication request to IDP I have to set these two lines.

```
BasicSecurityConfiguration config = (BasicSecurityConfiguration) Configuration.getGlobalSecurityConfiguration();
config.registerSignatureAlgorithmURI("RSA", SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA256);
```

This sets algorithm globally and would not work when you have multiple clients with different signature algorithms